# Get Current Date from TXT/LOG File

Tags: sql, logparser

Just started using LogParser recently, and I'm new to SQL queries.

I'm trying to get LogParser to find a log file with today's date, then outputting specific contents of the file into a text document. For example:

```
Select Text INTO D:\LogParser\output\BlahYYYY-MM-DD.txt
From 'C:\Logs\BlahYYYY-MM-DDBlah.log'
where Text like '%exception%'
```

How do I get my query to search for today's date in the file name, while keeping the YYYY-MM-DD format, and output to a text file with the same date and format?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to use functions in the FROM (nor in the INTO) clause.

If you can get the date from some other means, you could save the query to a file, specify e.g. `%MYDATE%` instead of the date, and then run the query specifying the parameter values as follows:

```
LogParser file:myQuery.sql?MYDATE=...
```